# Using stoichiometry to split a complex mineral

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, stoichiometry

Here is the problem I am stuck with, in particular just the first part of it.

[image]

I have calculated the moles $4.492 * 10^{-3} \,\mathrm{mol}$ and I am quizzed with regards to the equation that occurs. First assumption I am making is that the gas released is carbon dioxide.

Is it possible to separate out $\ce{(Mg_{x}Cu_{1-x})2(CO3)(OH)2}$ into simply the $\ce{(Mg_{x}Cu_{1-x})(CO3)}$ part that reacts with the dilute sulfuric acid to produce the carbon dioxide, the moles of which I know?

Comment: Please write informative titles. And, homework tag isn't for homework only. It's a symbol you could use whenever you wanted to indicate that you're looking for a thorough explanation, rather than a direct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to separate out $\ce{(Mg_{x}Cu_{1-x})2(CO3)(OH)2}$ into simply the $\ce{(Mg_{x}Cu_{1-x})(CO3)}$ part that reacts with the dilute sulfuric acid to produce the carbon dioxide, the moles of which I know?

- $4.492 * 10^{-3} \,\mathrm{mol}$ of $\ce{CO2}$ implies $4.492 * 10^{-3} \,\mathrm{mol}$ of $\ce{(Mg_{x}Cu_{1-x})2(CO3)(OH)2}$.
- $4.492 * 10^{-3} \,\mathrm{mol}$ of $\ce{(Mg_{x}Cu_{1-x})2(CO3)(OH)2}$ is 0.8167 g.
- Then, considering the atomic weights of C, O and H, subtract the contribution of these elements from 0.8167 g to determine the mass of $4.492 * 10^{-3} \,\mathrm{mol}$ of $\ce{(Mg_{x}Cu_{1-x})2}$.
- Then divide by 2 to get the mass of $4.492 * 10^{-3} \,\mathrm{mol}$ of $\ce{Mg_{x}Cu_{1-x}}$;
- Then use the atomic weights of Mg and Cu to solve for $x$.